# asp button remains disabled even after enabling it

Tags: jquery

I have an asp Add button inside RadGrid which performs an async postback. it also disables Save and Cancel button using jquery. i again enable them back when the command buttons are clicked.
but the html that is rendered still shows

`<input type="submit" ID="SaveButton" disabled="disabled"/>`

due to this, my OnClientClick event does not get fired.
why is it that the button is not enabled?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `.on`

```
$('#SaveButton').on('click',function(){
   //code.
});
```

Disabled elements don't fire mouse events. Most browsers will propagate an event originating from the disabled element up the DOM tree, so event handlers could be placed on container elements.

You can also do it as i said.

**example**

```
<div id = "click_fire_disable">
   <input type = "submit" id="anything" value = "I am disabled" disabled = "disabled" />
</div>
```

Now on `click_fire_disable` click event you can use it as submit button click event.

Above is the alternative way that i had found during my previous experience so share it to you.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hey Dipesh,the button is not disabled and the code behind button click event fires when it is clicked. only the clientclick event does not even though the button has been enabled using both `$(#SaveButton).removeAttr(disabled)` in client side and `SaveButton.Enabled=true;` in the code-behind. The buttons are not grayed-out and are clickable. But they are rendered as disabled="disabled"